# Совместимость IE8 vs IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, javascript

Доброго всем.
Есть 2 браузера IE v8.0.6 и v7.0.6
Вопрос в в том, чтобы сделать IE 8, как-бы что бы он понимал коды IE 7
Тэг в стиле:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

Данный тэг не помогает. Скрипт прекрасно работает в v7.0.6, но как его, без перепрограммирования заставить работать в старшей версии v8.0.6?
Ведь IE 8, должен по идее понимать всё от 7
Возможно это сделать на уровне тега?

*P.S. клиентов с 8-кой очень много, а скрипт подключен не простенький (я так сразу и не осилю, тем более по совместимости), поэтому решаю проблему через подгон по совместимости.*

Comment: напишите хоть в частности, что не понимает IE8? просто я сомневаюсь, что проблема в браузерах. На сколько я помню там только с версткой отличия но не с JavaScript поправьте если не прав

Comment: @binliz: DOM тоже отличается а следовательно клиентский код тоже может раличаться.

Comment: Спотыкается именно на этом  
`$(":text").focus(function () {
        inputInFocus = $(this);
    });`

Answer (score 1):

Эмуляйция IE7 должна сработать. Попробуйте в мета-тэге контент указать только один раз, так же этот тэг должен быть первым в `<head>`, не забудьте так же обязательно указать `DOCTYPE`. т.е. должно быть что-то вроде:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
   <title>........</title>

....
```